# Custom Nunit Category not showing properly in Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit, test-explorer

I'm trying to create a custom category for my tests, so we can list the requirements the tests are specifically testing.  Goal: Change the requirements, or a section of code that a requirement hits, then run the tests for that requirement. It also helps us keep track of tests so they're not duplicated. (we have over 400 requirements).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class RequirementAttribute : CategoryAttribute
{

    protected string requirementName;


    public RequirementAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.requirementName = name.Trim();
    }


    protected RequirementAttribute()
    {
        this.requirementName = this.GetType().Name;
        if (requirementName.EndsWith("Attribute"))
            requirementName = requirementName.Substring(0, requirementName.Length - 9);
    }

    public new string Name
    {
        get { return requirementName; }
    }
}
```

This is the code I"m using, which allows me to have a a test with multiple Requirements:

```
    [Requirement("000124")]
    [Requirement("000382")]
    [Requirement("000612")]
    [Category("Foo")]
    public void TestSomething(){}
```

This works, however in Test-Explorer I see:

```
Category[Foo](1) 
Category[000124](1) 
Category[000382](1)
Category[000612](1)
```

I want to see:

```
Category[Foo](1)
Requirement[000124](1)
Requirement[000382](1)
Requirement[000612(1)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Category("Requirement") to your decorations should work:

```
[Category("Requirement"), AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx